# Xpath combine multipe xpaths to one

Tags: xpath

I have the following xpaths:

`//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::p[1]//strong[2]`

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[10]/span/strong

//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[9]/span/strong
```

Is there is a way to combine them into one xpath?
I can use "|" so it would be:

```
 //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::p[1]//strong[2] 
| 
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[10]/span/strong
|
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[9]/span/strong
```

But it's a bit long for me, are there any other ways in my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine these xpath expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402613/how-do-i-combine-these-xpath-expressions)