# XPath: starts-with and lists of values

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

This xpath expression returns list of text values:

```
/some/xpath/expression/@Image
```

(this expression returns several values)

There is my another xpath expression:

```
/other/xpath/expression[starts-with(@Image, 'value')]
```

I need to select all `/other/xpath/expression/@Image` attributes of the given heritage whose value starts with the one of values that I got with `/some/xpath/expression/@Image`. How can I combine these expressions? Is this possible? I need something like this

```
/other/xpath/expression[starts-with(@Image, /some/xpath/expression/@Image)]
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402613/how-do-i-combine-these-xpath-expressions'

Comment: @RNS, nope, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/some/xpath/expression/@Image[starts-with(.,'value')]
```

will select all `@Image` attributes of the given heritage whose value starts with the string `value`.

---

**Update to address follow-up in comments:**

If `'value'` is not a literal but rather is to be obtained from elsewhere in the document, simply replace `'value'` with the XPath that selects the value:

```
/some/xpath/expression/@Image
   [starts-with(., /other/xpath/expression/@Image)]
```

Comment: I need to select all `/other/xpath/expression/@Image` attributes of the given heritage whose value starts with the one of values that I got with `/some/xpath/expression/@Image`.

Comment: @user23343436453: Answer updated to address your follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably clearer if we bind some variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="S" as="xs:string*" select="/some/xpath/expression/@Image"/>
```

There is my another xpath expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="O" as="xs:string*" select=/other/xpath/expression"/>
```

I need to select all /other/xpath/expression/@Image attributes whose value starts with the one of values in $s.

That would be

```
$O[some $s in $S satisfies(starts-with(., $s)]
```

Technical note: it's rare in XPath that such expressions are needed, but it happens here because you're doing a join that isn't an equi-join. For this, you need two range variables: the context item `"."` can be used for one of them, but the other needs to be explicit. In XSLT you can sometimes use `current()` as the second range variable.