# extract text with xpath from multiple sources

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I built a scraper to extract text fom 3 sites for my project. I want to use a single spider for the 3 sites.
2 of the sites has it contents in this structure:

```
<div id="site1">
   <p> this is a test </p>
</div>

<div id="site2">
   <p> this is a test </p>
</div>
```

and one has this:

```
<div class="site3">
   <p> <span> this is a test </span> </p>
</div>
```

I can extract the text from the 2 sites using this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="site1" or @id="site2" or @class="site3"]//p/text()').extract()
```

How do I modifiy this code to pull text from site3?

Comment: Maybe  this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406776/5600318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="site1" or @id="site2"]//p/text() | //div[@class="site3"]//p/span/text()').extract()
```